# Dailymotion: This `redirect_uri' ([URL]) isn't allowed by `client_id' configuration

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am working with the Dailymotion SDK for PHP:

https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php

Specifically, I am following the instructions here as a test:

https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php#authorization-grant-type

When I try to run this code, with the API Key and Secret that I generated, I am getting the following error:

This `redirect_uri' ([URL]) isn't allowed by`client_id' configuration.

Where [URL] is the specific application URL from which I am invoking my code.

Looking at the configuration for my application in Dailymotion, I see that the "Application Website" is the same as [URL], there is no discrepancy.

I am not seeing any settings or configurations issue to suggest that this URL would not be allowed.

Any thoughts, ideas or suggestions as to why this wouldn't work as such?

Answer (score 1):

You set a callback url when you create an API key at http://www.dailymotion.com/settings/developer 
For security reason, only redirect_uri starting with the callback URL provided are accepted, otherwise the api returns the error message you mention.

If your redirect_uri has to contain a dynamic part, you can use a slug this way when you specify your application callback URL: http://www.example.org/callback/[]. The  part becomes the dynamic part.

Without more details on the urls used, it's hard to tell more, but setting the proper "callback url" in the api key you're using should make it.

Comment: Yes, that's what we were trying, but it does not work.

Comment: Here's an outline of what we tried:  

In our application console, we set the Dailymotion application website to (for example):

http://ourwebsite.com/

Then we set the Callback URL to :

http://ourwebsite.com/test-dailymotion

But this doesn't work, we always get the same exception:

This `redirect_uri' (http://ourwebsite.com/test-dailymotion) isn't allowed by `client_id' configuration

let me know if I've missed something obvious

Comment: that's where you have to use the slug. Try with  ourwebsite.com/[slug]